# Connector name for angel eyes CCFL inverter

Tags: connector, identification

I have a CCFL inverter for  my car's headlight angel eyes. It seems they all respect some standard connector, but apparently the manufacturer of my headlights didn't get the memo :P, so until now I've been cutting wires and stitch them together on my car. I decided this has to stop and want to make a proper plug-and-play solution.

The problem is I can't identify the type of connector they use.

This is the connector that I want:

[image]
[image]

This would be the female connector, that I don't need but I thought it may help to identify:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Maybe next time add a comment explaining the downvote ? :( I've seen similar questions with no problems here...

Comment: It's a shopping/repair question, nothing to do with electronic design!

Comment: I think that's JST (Japan Solderless Terminals)

Comment: @LeonHeller: its an "identify this connector" question which is far from a shopping question.  Those seem to be allowed (I have a few in my history)

Comment: I think your question is OK, but dumping 5.5 Mpix images on us is not.  All the necessary information would be there with a little cropping and then downsizing to 630 width.  This is like saying you need a 10.0213 Ohm +-3% resistor, but more annoying since the browswer scrolls slowly.

Comment: I don't believe it's JST. They don't use flat blade pins.

Comment: @OlinLathrop Thank you for the heads up. I'll crop the images and donw-size them ;)

Comment: @OlinLathrop Now I realize it was a mistake: I've resized the images, but accidentally uploaded the originals :(. Anyhow, now should be much better :)

Comment: Much better, downvote undone.

Comment: For a second I thought it looked like this connector at allelectronics.com: http://www.allelectronics.com/make-a-store/item/CON-240/2-CONDUCTOR-LOCKING-CONNECTORS-W/LEADS/1.html but it isn't quite the same...

Answer (score 1):

I believe [I've manage to find it](http://www.tme.eu/en/details/nppw-03/raster-signal-connectors-250mm/ninigi/), but I still don't know how is it called.

Answer (score 0):

I know you can't identify the headlamp connector hence the film show but, can you identify the connector that would plug into the new invertor? If so, buy a mating half and swap the one shown in the picture. It's either choice A or choice B

Comment: This IS the new inverter. In the first two pictures is the connector I need, and the bottom 2 is the connector it plugs into ..

Comment: @NicolaeSurdu - if you cannot find a connector that suits either end then swap both ends with connectors you can source. OK it's better to find one end of course!!

Comment: This is what I'm trying to avoid: not being plug & play, to have to cut wires and stuff each time I change the inverter (which fails a lot :( )